# Cannot find module "./components/video_list"

Tags: reactjs

I am making youtube-search app. i have three component index for head component and rest two are:
1-video_list
2-video_item

coding for index.js

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-DOM';
import Search from './components/search';
import Video_list from './components/video_list';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
const  API_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      videos:[]
    };
    YTSearch({key:API_KEY,term:'hitesh choudhary'},(videos) => {
      this.setState({videos});
    });

  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Search />
        <Video_list videos={this.state.videos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector('.container'));
```

code for video_list

```js
    import React,{Component} from 'react';
import VideoListItem from './video_item';


class video_list extends Component {
  const videoItem = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
    return <VideoListItem video={video} />;
  });
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
          {videoItem}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default video_list;
```

code for video_item.js

```js
    import React,{Component} from 'react';

class video_item extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <li>{this.props.video}</li>
    );
  }
}

export default video_item;
```

console showing me Cannot find module "./components/video_list"

Comment: try checking your filename of video_list is 'video_list' or not

Comment: yes file name is  video_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capitalize component names in React or else JSX will consider them as HTML tags.

Declare components as

```
class VideoList
```

and

```
class VideoItem
```

Refer to the official documentation [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) for more details.